# how to set replication-factor at set level in Aerospike?

Tags: aerospike

I need to have replication-factor at set level in Aerospike. I am not able to find whether the Aerospike support this or not. Based on documentation I found that this can be configured at namespace level but my requirement is to configured at set level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to https://discuss.aerospike.com/t/changing-replication-factor/4733#how-to-configure-the-replication-factor-6 (pretty old but still applies) the replication-factor is configurable on a per-namespace basis.

A set is a logical unit which created dynamically and implicitly on the first record insertion.